# Password field with optional button to show password with vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I need to create a Password field with an optional button to show password with vaadin and to be obligatory (**).
I try to find out on my own but I didn't find anything I know is a simple thing, but I am new and I don't have much time left for my task. can someone provide me an example, please.

[image: that kind i need]

Answer (score 2):

`PasswordField field = new PasswordField();` in Vaadin10+ should be enough. Then you can configure it with setLabel(), serPlaceholder(), setRequired() and more.

Comment: It should be there by default, like shown in https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-text-field/html-examples/password-field-demos